# Tapestry zone update - does not retain value on page error

Tags: tapestry

I have a component which may be used within a Zone which is updated by a select.

This is roughly what my component looks like:

```
<div>
    <input
            t:type="textfield"
            t:id="integerPart"
            class="integerPart ${cssClass}"/>
</div>
```

This is roughly what the zone looks like:

```
<t:zone t:id="myZone" id="myZone">
    <t:mycomponent />
</t:zone>
```

When the select triggers the zone update the input is correctly updated with the given value. When the page is submitted I run some deep calculations on user-entered values and values from the database. When an error is triggered I record that error in a ValidationTracker and the page will be refreshed and the error is presented in the global  tag on my page.

The problem is that when the page is refreshed and presenting the errormessages the value of my textfield is lost. The reason for this is that tapestry rewrites the id within zones: 
http://tapestry.apache.org/ajax-components-faq.html

and these two implementation methods in AbstractTextField:

```java
@BeginRender
void begin(MarkupWriter writer)
{
    String value = tracker.getInput(this);
    // lots of code
}

@Override
protected void processSubmission(String controlName)
{
    String rawValue = request.getParameter(controlName);
    tracker.recordInput(this, rawValue);
    // lots of code
}
```

processSubmission is called when the page is submitted, and the current value in my textfield is stored in a map identified by the id: "integerPart_12a820cc40e", while when it is printed again when the page is reloaded to present the errormessage the component looks in the map for the key "integerPart". This will not yield a match and the textfield will be rendered empty (i.e. the value is lost).

I would think that this is a known problem in Tapestry and that there should be a quick and easy fix for it. I am solving this for now in a "not-so-quick-and-easy" way, which feels entirely wrong.

I extend TextField, and store the value with the id: "integerPart" in stead of "integerPart_12a820cc40e". And that is accomplished by this class:

```java
import org.apache.tapestry5.BindingConstants;
import org.apache.tapestry5.Field;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ValidationTracker;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.Environmental;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.Parameter;
import org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.TextField;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject;
import org.apache.tapestry5.services.Request;

public class ZoneFriendlyTextField extends TextField {
    @Inject
    private Request request;

    @Environmental
    private ValidationTracker tracker;

    // copied from Abstract Field - to be able to use it here
    @Parameter(value = "prop:componentResources.id", defaultPrefix = BindingConstants.LITERAL)
    private String localClientId;

    @Override
    protected void processSubmission(String controlName)
    {
        super.processSubmission(controlName);
        String submittedValue = request.getParameter(controlName);

        tracker.recordInput(new TextFieldInternalField(localClientId), submittedValue);
    }

    /**
     * This class is only used since the controlName of DateFieldset in a zone returns with a random id and
     * it is not possible to match against the right value when page-errors occur and we have to present
     * the user with the user-entered values again.
     * Should only be used for recording input in the tracker.
     */
    private static class TextFieldInternalField implements Field {
        String clientId;

        private TextFieldInternalField(String clientId) {
            this.clientId = clientId;
        }

        @Override
        public String getClientId() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getControlName() {
            return clientId;
        }

        @Override
        public String getLabel() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDisabled() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isRequired() {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could come up with a better solution to this problem! :-)

Note: I have sharpened the question a bit after the response from Lance Java. He gave a very good answer to my original question - but I don't think it will help me since my textfield is within a component which may be used multiple times in one page.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide an id (clientId), tapestry will use that instead of generating it's own dynamic value. Since you want a dynamic value, you could require a clientId parameter to be passed from the container. Note: For this approach, you will need to pass the clientId in the context of any ajax actions (eg eventlink).

MyComponent.Java

```
@Parameter(required=true, defaultPrefix="literal")
private String clientId;
```

MyComponent.tml

```
<input t:type="textfield" id="${clientId}" t:id="integerPart" class="integerPart ${cssClass}"/>
```

MyPage.tml

```
<t:mycomponent clientId="instance1" ... />
<t:mycomponent clientId="instance2" ... />
<t:loop source="1..10" value="current">
    <t:mycomponent clientId="prop:current" ... />
</t:loop>
```

Comment: That is an excellent point - but I forgot to mention that it's not necessarily right in my case. I oversimplified a bit too much. My textfield is part of a component which may be used multiple times on the same page, and some of those instances may have a zone around them. If I specify an ID - I will most likely have an id-conflict?

Comment: I will re-phrase my original question to clarify the part about zone and component.